# How to Disable SSL Certificate Check on SWIFTUI

Tags: swift, api, ssl, jsondecoder

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Jpj.png)

I am somewhat new to SwiftUI and XCode. I am currently trying to create an app that will show cryptocurrency prices and market data using the CoinGecko API all for personal use. I have been running into a variety of errors with the SSL Certification including:

*default TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9813)*

*HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1202 [3:-9813])*

I have read countless other guides trying to solve the problem, but have not come to a solution that works for SwiftUI on XCode 13.2.1

This included pasting in the following code into the Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>server.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Here is a snippet of my code, Please let me know if you have any solutions or other fixes to the jsondecoder XD. It is preferred to be thorough in the response, as in where to put certain code, etc. because I am still new to SwiftUI and may not be able to infer or know where to paste new lines of code.
Thanks in advance.

```
import Foundation

class GetCoinModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var coins = [MyResult]()
    
    
    
    
    func getCoinModel() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=1&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h")!
        
        do {
            
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                let coinData = try decoder.decode([MyResult].self, from: data)
                
                for r in coinData {
                    r.id = UUID()
                }
                self.coins = coinData
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this post, it seems to be similar to your issue. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658835

Comment: The API URL is already an https link though so I am not sure if this applies.

Comment: Working just fine for me. Ditch the info.plist entries they are not needed here. The link is https and the certificate is valid. The error must be something else.